# Node js attach vs launch

Tags: javascript, node.js

When we debug node js application what difference between Attach and Launch ??[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with Javascript / Node, it's a Visual Studio Code question.

Comment: Attach can debug a program already running, launch starts the program and immediately attaches a debugger. A program needs to have debugging enabled to be able to attach to it.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations):

> The best way to explain the difference between launch and attach is to think of a launch configuration as a recipe for how to start your app in debug mode before VS Code attaches to it, while an attach configuration is a recipe for how to connect VS Code's debugger to an app or process that's already running.